# Joining three tables with separate sets of identifying columns

Tags: sql, join

I have three tables that share one field with another table, so:

```
Employee_Data: EMP_ID, PHONE_EXTENSION
Outage_Data: DATE, EMP_ID
Phone_Data: DATE, PHONE_EXTENSION
```

I need to combine data where the agent data is matched with data in the other two tables. Basically, I need to combine the data from `Outage_data` and `Phone_data` (because it is all grouped by date) with `Employee_Data` as the "bridge".

I already have my SELECT and everything laid out like it needs to be; I just need help with the join.

*EDIT*
By Request, here is the full query. I tried not to do this for simplicity's sake:

```
    With Epi AS
 (SELECT  EMP_ID, PHONE_EXTENSION, Name, Manager, EWFMDeptname, Location From Employee_Data)
,

Shrink AS
 (SELECT DATE, EMP_ID, START_MOMENT, STOP_MOMENT, SEG_CODE FROM Outage_Data)
,

OutIn AS
 (SELECT date, logid, login, logout From PHONE_DATA)

 SELECT
    ISNULL(Shrink.DATE,OutIn.DATE) AS RowDate,
    ISNULL(Epi.EMP_ID,RTRIM(LTRIM(Shrink.EMP_ID))) AS Badge,
    ISNULL(Epi.PHONE_EXTENSION, OutIn.logid) AS [ACD/Extension],
    Epi.Name,
    Epi.Manager,
    Epi.EWFMDeptName,
    Epi.Location,
    ISNULL(Shrink.START_MOMENT, (SELECT Shrink.START_MOMENT FROM Shrink WHERE SHRINK.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' AND Shrink.EMP_ID = EPI.EMP_ID AND SHRINK.DATE = OutIn.DATE)) AS ShiftStart,
    ISNULL(Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, (SELECT Shrink.STOP_MOMENT FROM Shrink WHERE SHRINK.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' AND Shrink.EMP_ID = EPI.EMP_ID AND SHRINK.DATE = OutIn.row_date)) AS ShiftStop,
    OutIn.login AS Login,
    OutIn.logout AS Logout,
    Shrink.SEG_CODE AS OUTSEG,
    IIF(Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'FH', Shrink.START_MOMENT, NUll) AS OutStart,
    IIF(Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'FH', Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, NUll) AS OutStop,
    IIF(DateADD(minute, 5, Shrink.START_MOMENT) < OutIn.Login, CONVERT(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second ,Shrink.START_MOMENT,OutIn.Login)/60.0) ,0.00) AS Late,
    ISNULL(IIF(Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, OutIn.logout)/60.0) = NULL OR Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, OutIn.logout)/60.0) > 0.00, 0.00, ABS(Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, OutIn.logout)/60.0))), 0.00) AS [Left],
    IIF(OutIn.login IS NULL AND Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' ,DATEDIFF(minute,Shrink.START_MOMENT, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT), 0.00) AS NCNS
 FROM (Epi Right JOIN Shrink on Epi.EMP_ID = Shrink.EMP_ID) INNER JOIN OutIn ON (Shrink.DATE = OutIn.DATE) JOIN (
 WHERE Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'FH' or Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT'
 ORDER BY Badge;
```

Sorry its kind of messy. Again, Thank you

*EDIT2*

Per request, here is some of my data:

Shrink:

```
      EMP_SK    EMP_ID  EMP_LAST_NAME   EMP_FIRST_NAME  EMP_SORT_NAME   EMP_SHORT_NAME  EMP_SENIORITY   EMP_EFF_HIRE_DATE   NOM_DATE    SEG_CODE    START_MOMENT    STOP_MOMENT
-9.88181E+11    73485   BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20130812000 8/12/2013 0:00:00   10/6/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/6/2013 12:00:00  10/6/2013 21:00:00
-9.88181E+11    73485   BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20130812000 8/12/2013 0:00:00   10/7/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/7/2013 12:00:00  10/7/2013 21:00:00
-9.88768E+11    192329  BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20130715000 7/15/2013 0:00:00   10/7/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/7/2013 6:00:00   10/7/2013 15:00:00
-9.88741E+11    224579  BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20091214000 12/14/2009 0:00:00  10/7/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/7/2013 8:00:00   10/7/2013 17:00:00
-9.88741E+11    224579  BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20091214000 12/14/2009 0:00:00  10/8/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/8/2013 8:00:00   10/8/2013 17:00:00
-9.88181E+11    73485   BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20130812000 8/12/2013 0:00:00   10/8/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/8/2013 12:00:00  10/8/2013 21:00:00
-9.88768E+11    192329  BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    BLAH    20130715000 7/15/2013 0:00:00   10/8/2013 0:00:00   SHIFT   10/8/2013 6:00:00   10/8/2013 15:00:00
```

Epi:

```
     Badge  Name    NT Login    Email   MBadge  Manager Vendor  Business Unit   Business Unit Desc  Sub-Support Name    Segment Location    Subqueue    Phone Queue Title   EWFMDeptCode    EWFMDeptName    EWFMTeamCode    EWFMTeamName    ACD/Extension   Switch Name DomsID  DomsID2 DomsID3 Tech-ID (DPS)   Tech-ID2 (DPS2) KanaUserID  NetAgentID  Part_Time   Alias   Miscellaneous   Hiredate    Cost Center Jack    Building    QueueStatus Training Class  Trainer TeamCodeName    TeamCodeAbbr
    73485   blah    blah    blah    315413  blah    blah    blah    Service Desk Delivery   blah    Tech Support    blah    blah    Client Specialty Queue  Phone Agent blah    blah    Not Assigned    Not Assigned    4341776 AC03    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0   NULL    NULL    00:00.0 blah    blah    blah    Normal  Generic Class   Instructor  Not Assigned    Not Assigned
    224579  blah    blah    blah    626985  blah    blah    blah    Service Desk Delivery   blah    Tech Support    blah    blah    Client Specialty Queue  Phone Agent blah    blah    Not Assigned    Not Assigned    4341991 AC03    NULL    NULL    NULL    211212  NULL    0   0   0   NULL    NULL    00:00.0 blah    blah    blah    Normal  Generic Class   Instructor  Not Assigned    Not Assigned
    192329  blah    blah    blah    364970  blah    blah    blah    Service Desk Delivery   blah    Tech Support    blah    blah    Client Specialty Queue  Phone Agent blah    blah    Not Assigned    Not Assigned    4341937 AC03    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    0   0   0   NULL    NULL    00:00.0 blah    blah    blah    Normal  Generic Class   Instructor  Not Assigned    Not Assigned
```

OutIn:

```
row_date            logid   login                   logout
10/6/2013 0:00:00   4341776 10/6/2013 12:00:15  10/6/2013 21:00:26
10/7/2013 0:00:00   4341937 10/7/2013 6:04:48   10/7/2013 15:15:22
10/7/2013 0:00:00   4341991 10/7/2013 7:54:34   10/7/2013 17:00:39
10/7/2013 0:00:00   4341776 10/7/2013 12:00:16  10/7/2013 21:20:36
10/8/2013 0:00:00   4341937 10/8/2013 5:59:47   10/8/2013 15:01:31
10/8/2013 0:00:00   4341991 10/8/2013 7:58:46   10/8/2013 17:03:26
10/8/2013 0:00:00   4341776 10/8/2013 12:00:10  10/8/2013 14:32:20
10/8/2013 0:00:00   4341776 10/8/2013 14:32:20  10/8/2013 21:00:04
```

Thank you again

*Final EDIT*

I finally figured it out. Here is the completed code:

```
SELECT
    a.NOM_DATE AS RowDate, 
    a.EMP_ID AS Badge,
    ISNULL(a.[Extension], a.logid) AS [Extension],
    a.Name,
    a.Manager,
    a.DeptName,
    a.Location,
    a.START_MOMENT AS ShiftStart,
    a.STOP_MOMENT AS ShiftStop,
    a.login AS Login,
    a.logout AS Logout,
    a.SEG_CODE AS OUTSEG,
    IIF(a.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'FH', a.START_MOMENT, NUll) AS OutStart,
    IIF(a.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR a.SEG_CODE = 'FH', a.STOP_MOMENT, NUll) AS OutStop,
    IIF(DateADD(minute, 5, a.START_MOMENT) < a.Login, CONVERT(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second ,a.START_MOMENT,a.Login)/60.0) ,0.00) AS Late,
    ISNULL(IIF(Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, a.STOP_MOMENT, a.logout)/60.0) = NULL OR Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, a.STOP_MOMENT, a.logout)/60.0) > 0.00, 0.00, ABS(Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, a.STOP_MOMENT, a.logout)/60.0))), 0.00) AS [Left],
    IIF(a.login IS NULL AND a.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' ,DATEDIFF(minute,a.START_MOMENT, a.STOP_MOMENT), 0.00) AS NCNS
 FROM (SELECT l.row_date, l.logid, l.[login], l.logout, f.NOM_DATE, f.EMP_ID, f.START_MOMENT, f.STOP_MOMENT, f.SEG_CODE,
f.Badge, f.Extension, f.Name, f.Manager, f.Deptname, f.Location FROM LogInOutActual l
right Join 
(SELECT NOM_DATE, RTRIM(LTRIM(EMP_ID)) as EMP_ID, START_MOMENT, STOP_MOMENT, SEG_CODE, Badge,
Extension, Name, Manager, Deptname, Location FROM Shrink_Raw
LEFT OUTER JOIN Epicenter ON Shrink_Raw.EMP_ID = Epicenter.Badge 
WHERE Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA'
OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'JURY'
OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT'
OR Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'FH' or Shrink_Raw.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT') as f
on l.row_date = f.NOM_DATE AND l.logid = f.[ACD/Extension]) as a
WHERE Extension IS NOT NULL AND Name IS NOT NULL AND Manager IS NOT NULL and DeptName IS NOT NULL  AND Location IS NOT NULL
 ORDER BY RowDate, Badge;
```

After sleeping on it, I realized what to do. I did one join in a subquery and then another join in another subquery. It was so simple I feel stupid for posting it. Thank you to everyone that help the thinking process!

Comment: Is Outage_data.EMP_IP correct, or is that supposed to be Outage_Data.EMP_ID to join to Employee_data?

Comment: Sharing the select statement that you have written makes it so we don't have to guess (or rewrite the select for you).  joining three tables is no different than joining one table or 50 tables...you join each one in the from statement and specify which columns the join is on.  employee_date joins to outage_date on emp_id and employee_data joins to phone_data on phone_extention.  Give it a try and post your full select statement if you need further help

Comment: @BillHall - I just corrected that. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks mostly fine assuming you mean the RIGHT JOIN on Shrink so you don't miss any rows that don't have a matching Employee_Data row. There's just an extraneous `JOIN (` at the end of your `FROM` clause that I removed:

```
    With Epi AS
 (SELECT  EMP_ID, PHONE_EXTENSION, Name, Manager, EWFMDeptname, Location From Employee_Data)
,

Shrink AS
 (SELECT DATE, EMP_ID, START_MOMENT, STOP_MOMENT, SEG_CODE FROM Outage_Data)
,

OutIn AS
 (SELECT date, logid, login, logout From PHONE_DATA)

 SELECT
    -- These fields are always the same because of the inner join, 
    -- no need to check for nulls 
    -- ISNULL(Shrink.DATE,OutIn.DATE) AS RowDate,
    Shrink.DATE AS RowDate, 
    -- These fields are always the same because of the right join 
    -- unless there is no matching Epi row, then Epi.EMP_ID will 
    -- be null. You can just use Shrink.EMP_ID. If this field
    -- really needs to be trimmed, then we should be trimming
    -- this field in the RIGHT JOIN clause as well. 
    -- ISNULL(Epi.EMP_ID,RTRIM(LTRIM(Shrink.EMP_ID))) AS Badge,
    Shrink.EMP_ID AS Badge,
    ISNULL(Epi.PHONE_EXTENSION, OutIn.logid) AS [ACD/Extension],
    Epi.Name,
    Epi.Manager,
    Epi.EWFMDeptName,
    Epi.Location,
    -- I've added an alias to Shrink in the subqueries 
    -- to help clarify what is getting filtered.
    -- I also changed the where clause in the subquery 
    -- a bit so give this a try.
    -- If these are the problem fields, try not doing the 
    -- subqueries so you can get the actual data in the rows, 
    -- and mess around with just the subquery using values 
    -- from the original rows until you get the right START_MOMENT/STOP_MOMENT 
    ISNULL(Shrink.START_MOMENT, (SELECT Shrink.START_MOMENT FROM Shrink s WHERE s.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' AND s.EMP_ID = Shrink.EMP_ID AND s.DATE = Shrink.DATE)) AS ShiftStart,
    ISNULL(Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, (SELECT Shrink.STOP_MOMENT FROM Shrink s WHERE s.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' AND s.EMP_ID = Shrink.EMP_ID AND s.DATE = Shrink.DATE)) AS ShiftStop,
    OutIn.login AS Login,
    OutIn.logout AS Logout,
    Shrink.SEG_CODE AS OUTSEG,
    IIF(Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'FH', Shrink.START_MOMENT, NUll) AS OutStart,
    IIF(Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'FH', Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, NUll) AS OutStop,
    IIF(DateADD(minute, 5, Shrink.START_MOMENT) < OutIn.Login, CONVERT(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second ,Shrink.START_MOMENT,OutIn.Login)/60.0) ,0.00) AS Late,
    ISNULL(IIF(Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, OutIn.logout)/60.0) = NULL OR Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, OutIn.logout)/60.0) > 0.00, 0.00, ABS(Convert(decimal(10,2), DATEDIFF(second, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT, OutIn.logout)/60.0))), 0.00) AS [Left],
    IIF(OutIn.login IS NULL AND Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT' ,DATEDIFF(minute,Shrink.START_MOMENT, Shrink.STOP_MOMENT), 0.00) AS NCNS
 FROM (Epi Right JOIN Shrink on Epi.EMP_ID = Shrink.EMP_ID) INNER JOIN OutIn ON (Shrink.DATE = OutIn.DATE) 
 WHERE Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UABS' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'PPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'UPBA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'VACA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'JURY' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'GOVT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'LOA' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'BRVMNT' OR Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'FH' or Shrink.SEG_CODE = 'SHIFT'
 ORDER BY Badge;
```

Comment: Ah, then it comes down to whether `Phone_Data` joins to `Outage_Data` by `DATE` or if it joins to `Employee_Data` by `PHONE_EXTENSION`.

Comment: Thank you for looking at it. The code works up to a point, but it seems to be combining times across days. I will add some of my raw data so you can see what I mean. Thanks Again.

Comment: That would help clarify the problem you are having... one thing I noticed is your subquery for `ShiftStart` uses `OutIn.DATE` but the subquery for `ShiftStop` uses `OutIn.row_date`. Anyway, I'll take a look at your sample data when you post it.

Comment: Yeah, I actually changed some of the column names to make it more readable to others, so that is holdover from the original. Sorry about that. I added data, to give you a better idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Dantalion88, I've tweaked your query some more in my answer, and put some inline comments that I hope will help. I'm still assuming it's the ShiftStart/ShiftStop columns in the resultset that are giving you problems, and I think that had to do with the subqueries. If my changes don't fix it, then you should isolate those subqueries for the rows where they get fired.

Comment: I actually figured it out after sleeping on it. I marked yours as the answer so you can get credit for helping me so much. Thanks Again!

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * from employee_data e
join outage_data d on e.emp_id = d.emp_id
join phone_data p on d.date = p.date
```

Comment: @PM 77-1 I don't think so? 'Select date from ...' would have, but select * should be fine?

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT *
  FROM   Employee_Data ED

         INNER JOIN  Phone_Data PD ON
         ED.PHONE_EXTENSION = PD.PHONE_EXTENSION

         INNER JOIN Outage_Data OD ON
         ED.EMP_ID = OD.EMP_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing what your SELECT statement looks like, here's something that will return the complete table data:

```
SELECT *
FROM Employee_Data E
JOIN Outage_Data O on E.EMP_ID = O.EMP_ID
JOIN Phone_Data P on P.DATE = O.DATE
ORDER By P.DATE
```

You can adjust as needed.